# copy row data and insert in same table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to copy a record in a table are change the ID in MS access and I am getting an error

`"SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again., SQL state 23000 in SQLExecDirect"`

The SQL script is as follows

`$hh_copy = "insert into hh (rank_id,entry,R_date,fdp_code,village_code,Fname,Sname,gender,age,OI_num,id_num,HH_idnum,Alt_idnum,HH_name,HH_gender,HH_age,T_type,T_cat,hf5,hf18,hf59,hf60,hm5,hm18,hm59,hm60,hhsize,village_name,address,art_num,activate);`

```
SELECT hh.rank_id,hh.entry,hh.R_date,hh.fdp_code,hh.village_code,hh.Fname,hh.Sname,hh.gender,hh.age,hh.OI_num,'" . $new_id ."',hh.HH_idnum,hh.Alt_idnum,hh.HH_name,hh.HH_gender,hh.HH_age,hh.T_type,hh.T_cat,hh.hf5,hh.hf18,hh.hf59,hh.hf60,hh.hm5,hh.hm18,hh.hm59,hh.hm60,hh.hhsize,hh.village_name,hh.address,hh.art_num,hh.activate FROM hh WHERE hh.id_num = '" . $csv_line[0] ."'";
```

Comment: `because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship` seems to be the problem. What is your table structure?

Comment: remove primary key for selection and insertion